# Use string in column to find a word match in table to assign value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have a lookup table of data in Sheet1 where all the names in columns A and B will be unique, so no names in either A will exist in B and vice-versa. However, some names could include special characters like a hyphen or dash such as O'neil or Jamie-lee

[image]

I have another table of data in Sheet2, in which I need to use the text string in column D to find a matching name in Sheet1 (in either column A or B) and then assign the Score value of the row on sheet1 if a match is found into Sheet2 column E.

I have entered the matched score values in column E to demonstrate the outcome I require.
I don't mind using VBA or an Excel formula that works in XL2010

[image]

Is it possible to use a text string to find a word match, as I've only seen it the other way around, or am I looking at this the wrong way? I just don't seem to be getting anywhere.

I have change the code so often now trying to get it to work, I think I'm a bit lost, but this is the current state of my code that isn't working:

```
Sub TextSearch()

    Dim LR As Long
        LR = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim xLR As Long
        xLR = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    
    Dim oSht As Worksheet
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim strSearch As String, Score As String
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Set oSht = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Lastrow = oSht.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
        
    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        'Loop from Lastrow to Firstrow (bottom to top)
        For Lrow = xLR To 2 Step -1
            'Get the value in the D column to perform search on
            With .Cells(Lrow, "D")
                If Not IsEmpty(.Value) Then
                    strSearch = .Value
                
                    Set aCell = oSht.Range("A1:B" & Lastrow).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

                    For i = 2 To Lastrow
                        'Lookin column A on sheet1
                        If oSht.Cells(i, 1).Value = aCell Then
                            Score = oSht.Cells(i, 1).Offset(0, 2).Value
                            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Lrow, 4).Offset(0, 1).Value = Score
                        'Lookin Column B on sheet1
                        ElseIf oSht.Cells(i, 2).Value = aCell Then
                            Score = oSht.Cells(i, 2).Offset(0, 1).Value
                            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Lrow, 4).Offset(0, 1).Value = Score
                        End If
                    Next i
                
                
                End If
            End With
        Next Lrow
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Do the names always appear as the first word in the text search column?

Comment: Yes they do appear as the first word(s) in column D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you are attempting using a dictionary. It creates keys based off of Columns A and B on Sheet 1 with their scores stored as the item.

If you have duplicate names in Sheet 1 this won't fail, but it will only match against the first name encountered. There isn't enough data for it to make a distinction that I can see.

```
Sub findmatches()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim name As String
    
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    With ws1
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Getting last row
        For i = 2 To lr
            If Not dict.exists(.Cells(i, 1).Value) Then 'Checking if name is in dictionary
                dict.Add .Cells(i, 1).Value, .Cells(i, 3).Value 'Adding name and score
            End If
            If Not dict.exists(.Cells(i, 2).Value) Then 'Checking if name is in dictionary
                dict.Add .Cells(i, 2).Value, .Cells(i, 3).Value 'Adding name and score
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    
    With ws2
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lr
            name = Split(.Cells(i, 4).Value, " ")(0) 'Splitting the string into an array and taking the first element
            If dict.exists(name) Then 'Checking if name is in dict
                .Cells(i, 5).Value = dict(name) 'assigning score to Column 5
            Else
                .Cells(i, 5).Value = 0 'No name score = 0
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That does work and I thank you, but I don't understand how its working, could you add some explanations to the sections so I can understand how it is working within the "with" part of the code?

Comment: I added a bunch of comments to the code.

Comment: Thank you for this. I have never come across Scripting. Dictionary, but after googling it I think I now understand. It is building a list from ws1 and then checking it against ws2.

Comment: Yes exactly, keys must be unique in a dictionary and it has that nice `.exists` method to check if your key is already in the dictionary, at which point we can add if not there on ws1 or extract the value associated to the key on ws2 if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 365, this is possible via an (extended) array formula. Paste into E2 and copy down.

```
=LET(lookup,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$5,delimiter," ",string,$D2,array,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$5,data,INDEX(array,MOD(SEQUENCE(ROWS(array)*COLUMNS(array),,0),ROWS(array))+1,ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(ROWS(array)*COLUMNS(array))/ROWS(array),0)),values,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(string,delimiter,"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),list,IFERROR(INDEX(lookup,1+MOD(MATCH(values,data,0)-1,ROWS(array))),0),TRANSPOSE(FILTER(list,list<>0)))
```

Breaking this down

```
=LET(lookup, Sheet1!$C$2:$C$5,
delimiter, " ",
string, $D2,
array, Sheet1!$A$2:$B$5,
data, INDEX(array,MOD(SEQUENCE(ROWS(array)*COLUMNS(array),,0),ROWS(array))+1,ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(ROWS(array)*COLUMNS(array))/ROWS(array),0)),
values, FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(string, delimiter,"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),
list, IFERROR(INDEX(lookup,1+MOD(MATCH(values,data,0)-1,ROWS(array))),0),
TRANSPOSE(FILTER(list, list<>0))
)
```

Assign:

- `lookup` as the lookup range to take the values for the results
- `delimiter` and `string` as the sentence to test and how to split it for a dynamic array
- `array` as the data lookup array to test
- `data` is a calculated 1D array of all values from `array` stacked
- `values` is a calculated 1D array from your sentence to test
- `list` is then an array of the row 'indices' where matches are found (mod #rows so it's column independent)

Finally, that list is filtered of any non-hits then transposed to give a spill list of all the matches from the `lookup` values.