# Excel lookup index that can return multiple results

Tags: excel, filter, lookup, multiple-instances

I want to do an index lookup that can potentially return multiple results.  I'm trying filter, and that doesn't seem to be working.  Any suggestions?

My spreadsheet looks like this:

```
FinalResult tab:
A             V
Index  ....   ErrorState
A1234  ....   No results
A3400  ....   #SPILL!
```

with V formula being: `=FILTER(List_State_11.18.2021!A2:R81,List_State_11.18.2021!A2:A81=FinalResult!A2, "No results")`

```
And the List_State_11.18.2021 tab looks like this:

    A          J
    Device ... Display_Text
    A1234  ... Not Found
    A2345  ... Fault
    A3400  ... Not Found
    ...
```

But every Device in List_state tab does not have Display_Text to find.  Ie. Not every Index on the FinalResult tab has a fault to find in List_state.  There's about 80 items in List_state with repeats for devices (multiple faults), and 300 indices in FinalResult with no repeats for index (exclusive).  I want to return all faults found for each index, if found.

In my use of filter, it's finding all No results or #Spill!, with no other results.  How do I fix what I have, or what other method can I use to find no, one, or multiple faults in my List_state tab, and put it in my FinalResult tab?

I checked, and the #spill! is not one with multiple matches.  The index for the spill result is not in the List_state tab.

I've never done a lookup like this, so it's more than likely user error.  Usually I do a vlookup where it's finding one device result and not multiple results. When I googled it, it seemed to suggest filter, but I could be mistaken. I haven't seen an example where the multiple results returned/found are put in the one row/column and not spilling to a second column like I want. I'm not convinced filter and my formula is ultimately what I need.
[filter](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2020/06/17/excel-filter-function/)
[multiple](https://www.get-digital-help.com/how-to-return-multiple-values-using-vlookup-in-excel/)

Comment: try: `=@FILTER(List_State_11.18.2021!A2:R81,List_State_11.18.2021!A2:A81=FinalResult!A2, "No results")` or XLOOKUP: `=XLOOKUP(FinalResult!A2,List_State_11.18.2021!A2:A81,List_State_11.18.2021!A2:R81, "No results")`

Comment: It looks like your @filter idea, which looks the same as mine except the @, is returning the index instead of the Display_Text.  XLookup is looking the same as my filter one, with #spill! or no results returned

Comment: You are returning multiple columns: `List_State_11.18.2021!A2:R81` change that to the single column you want to return ie: `List_State_11.18.2021!R2:R81`  I thought you wanted all the columns returned and were getting multiple rows.

Comment: @ScottCraner do you mean =@FILTER(List_State_11.18.2021!R2:R80,List_State_11.18.2021!A1:A80=FinalResult!A2, "No results") because that's returning #Value! for all

Comment: your second range starts at row 1 and the first at row 2, they need to match.

Comment: @ScottCraner I'm not clear on that.  the Final Result index column is what we are matching for the List_State first column for the device, and returning the display_text. row 1 does not necessarily match on both sheets and neither does the second.

Comment: `List_State_11.18.2021!A1:A80` and `List_State_11.18.2021!R2:R80` do not have the same number of rows.  The first starts on row 1 `A1` and the second starts on row 2 `R2`.  They need to be the same number of rows.  Change them both to start on row 1 or row 2.

Comment: Also since you are dragging the formula down, they should be absolute: `=@FILTER(List_State_11.18.2021!$R$2:$R$80,List_State_11.18.2021!$A$2:$A$80=FinalResult!A2, "No results")`

Comment: Looks like it's finding it with this, but I know there's a couple that would find multiple display_text because of duplicate device in the List_State tab.  How do I get it to add them in the result column? =@FILTER(List_State_11.18.2021!$J$2:$J$80,List_State_11.18.2021!$A$2:$A$80=FinalResult!A2, "NA")  So if it found Not Found and also Fault, I want the result to show Not Found; Fault

Comment: Remove the `@` it is only returning the first, but realize any duplicate finds will spill down and you will need to have empty cells for it to spill.  If you want them all to return into the same cell wrap in TEXTJOIN.

Comment: Use `Transpose` to make your results spill across columns and not down rows which will result in the #SPILL error you are seeing. I coded something moderately similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70025120/3688861

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
=LET(data, List_State_11.18.2021!J:J, filterlist, List_State_11.18.2021!A:A, lookup, A2, TRANSPOSE(FILTER(data, filterlist=lookup, "No Results")))
```

For use with TEXTJOIN, you wouldn't need to transpose the results

```
=LET(data, List_State_11.18.2021!J:J, filterlist, List_State_11.18.2021!A:A, lookup, A2, results, FILTER(data, filterlist=lookup,"NA"), TEXTJOIN("; ", TRUE, results))
```

Comment: Thank you! :) Nice, it seems to be putting the second Display_Text found in the column next to the original formula column.  Is there a way for it to put both in the same column?

Comment: That's what a spill range does. Ultimately, you need to work out how you want your data displayed (and communicate it well). Multiple results can't go in the same column as they would overwrite the cell contents below (this is the source of your #SPILL error). You can set it so further columns are used to display your results (which this answer does), you could use TEXTJOIN to concatenate all results into a single cell or you could return a single result. These are pretty much your only options.

Comment: Any idea how to use textjoin to put them all in the same cell? That's what I meant...I wanted to put the display_text all in one cell, maybe with a semicolon between them or something

Comment: Figured it out! to join with semicolon,       =TEXTJOIN("; ",TRUE,(LET(data,List_State_11.18.2021!J:J,filterlist,List_State_11.18.2021!A:A,lookup,A9,TRANSPOSE(FILTER(data,filterlist=lookup,"NA")))))

Comment: I used textjoin like this.  Thanks! =TEXTJOIN("; ",TRUE,(LET(data,List_State_11.18.2021!S:S,filterlist,List_State_11.18.2021!A:A,lookup,A2,TRANSPOSE(FILTER(data,filterlist=lookup,"NA")))))

Comment: So it comes out like this for ones with multiples: Not Found; Fault