# File originally opened with presumably 365 version opened/saved with 2016. Formulas not working in 365 now

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I have a file that was originally saved/worked on from a documents folder under One *Drive*.  It was then moved to a share drive, and when I opened it, it was using Excel 2016.  I found out some formulas/functions are only available in 365, so I got that installed on my computer, and the next time I opened it, it says it's using excel 365.  However, the formulas are not working still.

I have a tab, List_State_6.10.2022 that looks like this:

```
     A                    G         ...  J          ...  S
1    Device    Org   ...  component ...  Display    ...  Comp+Display
     ABC123    co    ...  part1     ...  Not Found  ...  part1+Not Found
     ABC234    co    ...   part2    ...  ok         ...  part2+ok
     ABC123    co    ...   part3    ...  ok         ...  part3+ok
```

I have a FinalResult tab that is trying to do multiple lookups in this tab above to find states, and appending each one found for same device number into the same cell for w2.  This used to work and I'm not sure why it stopped working.

```
    A            W
1   Device   ... Component+ErrorState
2   ABC123   ... #Name?
```

w2 should show: part1+Not Found;part3+ok

The cell formula in w2 is:

```
{=TEXTJOIN("; ",TRUE,(_xlfn.LET(_xlpm.data,List_State_6.10.2022!S:S,_xlpm.filterlist,List_State_6.10.2022!A:A,_xlpm.lookup,A2,TRANSPOSE(_xlfn._xlws.FILTER(_xlpm.data,_xlpm.filterlist=_xlpm.lookup,"NA")))))}
```

This formula returns #name?

I tried removing the _xlpm's and it looks like this but still returns #name?

```
=TEXTJOIN("; ",TRUE,(LET(data,List_State_6.10.2022!S:S,filterlist,List_State_6.10.2022!A:A,lookup,A2,TRANSPOSE(FILTER(data,filterlist=lookup,"NA")))))
```

I'm a little unsure here why it has #name? now and not a found error, or NA.  It used to work.  When I open the old spreadsheet that worked fine, it says it's opening it in 365, and when I drag the formula cell down, it fills all with #name?. I'm not sure why the formula has stopped working if I'm using 365 now.

My question is how do I get this formula to work again?

Thank you!

Update:
This was my old question, and it seemed to work back then, but now it's not working. I never used a web version.
[stack overflow index return mult results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70023831/excel-lookup-index-that-can-return-multiple-results)

Comment: Try saving a new copy again in 365? As in save as.

Comment: @findwindow I tried moving it to my one drive folder, opened the spreadsheet, save-as excel workbook newName, and the formulas still show #name?

Comment: Welp, I was hoping it would work like a windows reboot. Without the file, I can't replicate the issue to troubleshoot :/

Comment: @chrisneilsen It wouldn't accept the formula doing that, but I did it by hand and pulled it down the row, and it still says #name?.  I knew that would happen because of my comment in the description where I said, "I tried removing _xlpm's", which included xlfm's too.

Comment: Did you try typing `=LET` and/or `=FILTER` in an empty cell? Does Excel show the formula as existing?

Comment: @P.b =LET gives #name?

Comment: @pb when I type =filter, it shows the function but I didn't select it, but it seems to exist. =let doesn't show any suggested functions

Comment: Thought so. I had the same with our company for a long time. `LET` is introduced later then `FILTER` and other functions. You should check with IT when they plan to rollout an update.

Comment: @P.b good idea! Maybe I'm missing an update since I just installed 365! :)

Comment: @Michele, you can see your version under `File/Account/About Excel`

Comment: @chrisneilsenMicrosoft Excel for  Microsoft 365 MSO 16.0.13127.21452 64 bit

Comment: @chrisneilsen Version 2008 build 13127.21506

Answer (score 1):

The answer to *how do I get this formula to work again?* is install a version of Excel that supports all the used functions.

The `_xlfn.`, `_xlfm.`, `_xlws.` prefixes indicate the function is valid but not supported in the installed version of Excel.  They should disapear when the workbook is opened in a version that supports the function.

Seems `LET` was introduced in [Version 2009 (Build 13231.20262)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/monthly-channel-archived#version-2009-september-28)